# Como decodificar uma array JSON [{},{}] no meu android

Tags: java, android, json, array-multidimensional

Como eu transformo essa *string* em uma array no meu Android de forma que eu possa manipulá-la?

```
[{"id":"1","login":"Admin","senha":"Admin","nome":"Admin","msg":"Eba","logado":"0"},
{"id":"7","login":"Daniel","senha":"1234","nome":"Daniel","msg":"","logado":"0"},
{"id":"8","login":"Dannark","senha":"1234","nome":"Dannark","msg":"","logado":"0"},
{"id":"9","login":"Joosi","senha":"99487452","nome":"Joosi","msg":"","logado":"0"}]
```

Eu tenho tentando dessa forma:

```
    /*Conn.response é a minha array*/
    JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(Conn.response).nextValue();
    id = object.getString("0");
    nome = object.getString("3");
    msg = object.getString("4");
```

Porem só funciona no seguinte formato:

```
{"0":"1","1":"Admin","2":"1234","3":"Adm","4":"message","5":"0"}
```

Comment: Tens de por mais informação. Como está declarado o teu array `Conn`?

Comment: Jorge B. Na verdade a variável Conn.resonse é uma string, e que precisaria trasformar-la em uma array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use o `JSONArray` em vez do `JSONObject`, usando o contrutor [JSONArray(java.lang.String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html#JSONArray%28java.lang.String%29).

No seu exemplo ficaria assim:

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(Conn.response);
```

Assumindo que `Conn.response` é do tipo `String`. Onde cada elemento do `JSONArray` é um `JSONObject`.

Para acessar os valores:

```
JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(0);

String id = object.getString("id");
String login = object.getString("login");
//... E por assim para cada campo que quiser do objeto.
```

Comment: Realmente Conn.response é do tipo String, mas como poderia pegar os valores? Nao to conseguindo com _id = array.getString("0")_

Comment: Pronto, adicionei um exemplo de como acessar os campos dos objetos no array. Lembrando que no array, cada elemento é um JSONObject com suas propriedades.

Comment: Ei amigo, Voce é fera, funcionou perfeitamente! ^^
Ainda tenho que tentar entender o Codigo, mas agora ja consigo pegar o valor de qualquer campo, Muito Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Recomendo usar o [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), aqui vai um exemplo:

1.- Instancie um objeto `Gson`:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
```

2.- Pegue o `Tipo` correspondente for para você, por exemplo `List<String[]>` (Note que você não pode fazer algo como `List<String[]>.class` devido ao [tipo de rasura do Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html)):

```
Type type = new TypeToken<List<String[]>>() {}.getType();
```

3.- Finalmente, converta do JSON para o `tipo` definido:

```
List<String[]> yourList = gson.fromJson(yourJsonString, type);
```

Fonte: [Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17970128/how-to-convert-string-array-to-object-using-gson-json)